# Is this method of create Singleton thread safe?

Tags: java, singleton

This is not a discussion of whether or not Singleton is good or bad. It is about creating singleton. The way I understand Singleton is that it is a class that at anytime there should exists at most of one object. That is if several classes instantiate a singleton at the same time then they would share a single instance of that singleton.
The problem with singleton is that once it is created it will exist for the duration of an application. With my method you can create and have a Singleton garbage collected any time if it is not being use any more. Well I need to have an enum (Singleton!) to create all other Singleton. I think my method is reflection and serialized safe but I am not sure if there is any problem with thread.
My method to create singleton is as follow:

First any class that want to be singleton has to extend the following class

```
public abstract class Singleton {
    public Singleton(SingletonFactory.SingletonParam singletonParam) {
        if (singletonParam == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("singletonParam cannot be null)");
        }
    }

    // For singleton to release resources.    
    public abstract void destroy(SingletonFactory.SingletonParam singletonParam);
}
```

SingletonParam is going to be an abstract class inner class which cannot have an object which is a SingletonParam in a polymorphism sense instantiate outside of its container class.
This is not intended to have subclasses extends the Singleton class at runtime. It is for classes that are singletons by having a static instance. My method does not require any static instance of the singleton class.
The container is the following class

Note: after reading the answer from Stephen C, I made the change to initialize the HashMap from the constructor and I do not see why it is not thread safe.

```
public enum SingletonFactory {
    INSTANCE;

    enum SingletonList {
       A,
       B,
      ......
    }

   private final HashMap<String, SingletonInfo> mfSingletonInfoHashMap = new HashMap<>();

    // Added after @Stephen C answer
    SingletonFactory() {
        mfSingletonInfoHasmap.put(A, final new SingletonInfo());
     // put all the members of the SingletonList here.   
        At this time the  Singleton member of the SingletonInfo is null.   
        It will be instantiated when a class call getSingleton
     }

    private class SingletonInfo {
        final Set callingObjects = new HashSet();
        Singleton singleton;
    }

   public Object getSingleton(SingletonList inList, Object object) {
      final SingletonInfo singletonInfo = mfSingletonInfoHashMap.get(inList);
       synchronized (singletonInfo) {
              if (singletonInfo.callingObjects.add(object)) {
                  if (singletonInfo.singleton == null) {
                      singletonInfo.singleton = createSingleton(singletonClassName);
                    }
              } else {
                  throw new RuntimeException("getSingleton(" + singletonClassName + ") has already been called and not released");                 
              }
      return singletonInfo.singleton;
  }

    public void releaseSingleton(SingletonList inList, Object object) {
          SingletonInfo singletonInfo = mfSingletonInfoHashMap.get(inList);

          synchronized (singletonInfo) {
            singletonInfo.callingObjects.remove(object);
            if (singletonInfo.callingObjects.isEmpty()) {               
                singletonInfo.singleton.destroy(new SingletonParam() {
            });
            singletonInfo.singleton = null;
          }
      }
  }

    private Singleton createSingleton(SingletonList inList) {
        switch(inList) {
           case SingletonA:
               return new SingletonA(new SingletonParam() {});
           ......
        }
    }

    public abstract class SingletonParam {
        private SingletonParam() {

        }
    }
}
```

Well the above is not quite right since you have to extends the HashSet that contains the CallingObjects in the SingletonInfo to implement equality by reference and not equal in the default implementation.

Since an instance of a subclass of `SingletonParam` cannot be instantiate outside of `SingletonFactory` the only way you can create a singleton object is by calling `SingletonFactory.INSTANCE.getSingleton(you_singleton_class_name, this)`

Comment: Why don't you just use a `WeakReference`?

Comment: WeakReference on what?

Comment: To your singleton that you want to be garbage collectable.

Comment: You mean return a WeakReference?

Comment: I mean cache it in a WeakReference.

Comment: Since I learn programming just by coding and no formal training I do not understand you yet. I have to take up some reading to understand what you mean. I have some idea what you mean but if a singleton need to release resources then the class that call getSingleton has to call releaseSingleton so that the singleton can call its destroy method to release resource any way right?

Comment: Consider making your resource `Closable` and using *try with resources*, or implementing the `finalize` method (not guaranteed to be called, but could be good enough)

Comment: @Bohemiian I think it is the caller of getSingleton job to call releaseSingleton. In my implementation I has a checkMemoryLeak method for debugging purpose to check for call to getSingleton without calling releaseSingleton. I will take a close look at your suggestion right now I have no idea where to use your suggestion in my code. I thought about overriding finilize to call chekMemoryLeak but I know it may not be called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original version is not thread-safe.  The `getSingleton` method was reading and updating the `HashMap` without synchronizing on anything.

---

> I see there maybe a problem when there is no SingletonInfo associates with a singleton class name yet.

Correct.

---

This is about the updated version of the code:

> In that case I can just populate my hashmap with all the singleton class names with empty CallingObjecs and null Singleton and then synchronize on the SingletonInfo. Does that sound right?

Yes, provided that:

1. the initialization happens in the `SingletonFactory` constructor,
2. the hashmap is safely published, and
3. nothing changes the hashmap after it has been the factory has been constructed.

However, that would seem to defeat one of the advantages of your initial implementation; i.e. that the singleton factory is no *a priori* knowledge of the singletons.

A better approach (i.e. an approach that preserves the advantages of your original attempted solution) would be to either synchronize access to the `HashMap`, or use a `ConcurrentHashMap` ... and its special atomic operations.

---

> Since I learn programming just by coding and no formal training ...

You *at least* need to read a good text book on Java Concurrency, if you are going to learn to use Java concurrency properly.  Try Goetz et al.

(You need need to understand the principles of Java concurrency.  You are unlikely to learn them by trial and error.)

It is (IMO) concerning that you are so focused on making the singleton design pattern work, when the "received wisdom" is that singletons are a bad idea.  Have you considered Dependency Injection and its advantages?

The other thing is that these are not true singletons.

- The implied semantics of your `Singleton` class contradict its name.  There can be multiple instances of `Singleton` ...
- There is nothing to prevent someone from creating multiple instances of a given `Singleton` subclass.  Given your implementation approach, there needs to be a non-private constructor for each suclass in order for the factory to work.
- Unless you declare your `Singleton` subclasses as `final`, that would provide another route to breaking singleton-ness.

In short, I'm not convinced that this infrastructure you are building is going to achieve your goal of implementing (true) singletons better.

Comment: It read the HashMap but the CallingObjectst is synchronized so isn't it in if (singletonInfo.callingObjects.add(object)) the thread has to wait if another thread is also want to get the same singleton object and has the lock?

Comment: I see there maybe a problem when there is no SingletonInfo associates with a singleton class name yet. In that case I can just populate my hashmap with all the singleton class names with empty CallingObjecs and null Singleton and then synchronize on the SingletonInfo. Does that sound right?

Comment: I know I have to initialize the hashmap in the constructor but I do not see why that if I changed the values, not keys of the hashmap after initialization would cause problem. Why is it not save in SingletonInfo a = get(singletonclassname) and then synchronized(a). I can see dead lock but not inconsistency problem. I read about ConcurrentHashmap a long while ago and I do not think it will do the job, maybe I am wrong about what it is and will go back to read about it again. I can synchronize the whole method but it will slow down everything but I think what I try to do can be made thread safe.

Comment: @HoanNguyen - What do you mean by "change the values"?

Comment: The key are fixed, I should make them into enum. That is one knows in advance what classes extends the abstract singleton class, thus in the constructor of SingletonFactory, the HashMap is populated with all these singleton class names as key but with the Singleton member of SingletonInfo null. Then when a class called getSingleton it will synchronize the singletonInfo associated with the singleton and fetch or create the Singleton member of the SingletonInfo. The value is the singletonInfo with associated key singleton class name.

Comment: Well in that case, since you are not changing the values, what I said above about the HashMap still applies.

Comment: No the value singletonInfo will not change but its member singleton will change. This is not intended to have dynamics subclasses of the abstract singleton class at run time. The abstract singleton class is to ensure that class that is intended to be Singleton is not accidentally create outside the SingletonFactory. I should create an enum SingletonList inside SingletonFactory and then declare getSingleton(SingletonList memberOfList, Object). What I am trying to do is creating singleton but do not require "singleton" object to be static as it is previously have to be.

Comment: @HoanNguyen - Please read my answer again.  I am not going to repeat myself.  If you have specific questions about what I said in my answer, I will comment on them.  However, it is important that you actually read and understand answers instead of repeatedly asking the same question in comments.

Comment: I see now why it is not thread safe. I was thinking of pointer points to the same location and not realize that the singletonInfo object is copied to register and then manipulate before copying back to the memory. Thus if there is no lock then several copies of the singletonInfo can be copied and thus lead to inconsistency. If I lock it by synchronized my method which I tried to avoid then it would be thread safe.

Comment: I do not understand why there can be several instance of a Singleton as I define above. Outside of the SingletonFactory the SingletonParam cannot be subclass and thus instantiate and therefore class that extends the abstract Singleton cannot be instantiate anywhere except by SingletonFactory. In the SingletonFactory a singleton can be instantiate several time but at any time there is only at most one instance. For me that is what singleton mean.

Comment: Again I state right in the beginning this is not about if singleton is bad or not. My problem with dependency injection is, it is very slow the first time an application is launched especially for mobile. I do not have time to dig into the dagger open source to know how they handle class that annotate with @singleton. Are they singletons?

Comment: Did I mention that you **need** to read a text book on Concurrency??  *"For me that is what singleton means"* - Sounds like you need a text book on Design Patterns *as well*!  I don't have the time to help you, especially if you are insistent on ignoring my advice.